# What are the main concepts behind building the plasma effect with GSLS?

Tags: shader, glsl, color, fragment-shader, 2d-graphics

By the plasma effect I mean an animation that looks like this:

[image]

I have seen some codes, like these

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xst3zN

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tdGWX

and messed with the code to try to grasp it, but I'm not understanding what is going on, for example, if there's a main math concept behind it that makes the effect possible, or a shader technique that I don't know about.

Comment: There is very nice intro/discussion on the topic here: https://thebookofshaders.com/13/

Comment: Looks like each point on a grid has an oscillating texture coordinate (just one), which is interpolated and used to lookup a colour in a 1D gradient texture. Also the grid is shifting to the left. As far as plasma effects go, this one isn't even very plasma-y.